# find GAE datastore entities by CompositeFilterOperator in a key list subset

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two dependent classes : let's say

- a product
- an eventual favorite flag per user on that product (many users can flag a product as favorite)

When I need to execute filtering in the subset of user favorite products I find my self with an issue : no API for that

for example: I want to search in hte favorite products of user 1, products having the tag 'sport' and the color 'blue'

I can either

- do a CompositeFilter on the tag and color criteria, then iterate on all products (thousands) to find which are in the favorite id list !!! WOW! :-)
- find the subset of favorites, and do all other criteria filtering manually (programatically, leaving the datastore API). YESSSS!!!
- The last but from far not the least: add a list of favorite user ids in the product itself (the favorite column), so that each time a user puts a product in its favorites, all 120 index writes are rewritten. COOOOL!!!

Ok I'm cheating, there's a solution : I can read the Favorite entity, then use the ids in the query on products with a huge (id=x1 or id=x2 or...) there's here a risk to find myself out of the limit of the query size. Therefore I should handle pagination and indirect cursor through the two entities to obtain a read for a very simple requirement...

Soooo Yeah... ideas?

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi
http://1vu.fr

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Key_filters) and [property filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Property_filters). If I understand your data above, the query would be:

```
Query q =  new Query("Product");

// favourite product key filter (max 30 in listOfProductIDs because this is IN query)
query.addFilter(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY,
                        Query.FilterOperator.IN, listOfProductIDs);

// add the property filters
query.addFilter("color", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, "blue");
query.addFilter("tag", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, "sport");
```

Comment: Hi Peter, 

Sorry I didn't look back for the answers: the issue with the FilterOperator.IN is that a request is made for each of the IN possibilities (that's why it is limited to 30).
You're describing the solution (1.) I gave + (using the IN query, which is not acceptable in terms of performance and resource consumption)